# FTP delete and FTP unlink not working

Tags: php, file, ftp, delete-file

I want to delete a specific file withn an FTP folder using PHP.

Here's the work I have done so far: This is the code I'm using to echo the image view and the checkbox so that users can select an image and then click a delete button.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $r; $i++)
{   
    echo "<form action='somephpfile.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"
        . "<img src='$images[$i]' width='50' height='50' />"
        . "<input type='checkbox' name='$i' value='Restaurant' />"
        . $images[$i]
        . "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete' />"
        . "</form>";
}
```

This is how I try to delete the file that the user wants to delete:

```
$images = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "somefolder");
$r = count($images);

for ($i = 0; $i < $r; $i++)
{
    if ($selected_checkbox = $_POST['$i'])
    {   
        $myFile = "$images[$i]";
        $fop = fopen($myFile, "w") or die("can not open file");
        $fclose($fop); 
        unlink($fop); 

        if (ftp_delete($conn, $myFile))
        {
            echo "$file deleted successful\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "could not delete $file\n";
        }
    }
}

ftp_close($conn);
```

Why is this example not working?

Answer (score 2):

The following line of code doesn't correctly compare `$selected_checkbox` with `$_POST['$i']` but assigns the posted value instead, which always evaluates as `true`:

```
if ($selected_checkbox = $_POST['$i'])
```

You want to use the **comparison operator `==`** instead of the assignment operator `=`. Take a look at the section *Comparion Operators* in this [Overview of PHP Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp).